# Why is my Decrypt Method throwing a "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid" Cryptographic Exception

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-3.5, encryption-symmetric

This is a really common exception, but obviously none of the solutions I've found have resolved my issue.

I have an Encrypt and a Decrypt method; I encrypt a string and write it to a file, then read the string from the file and decrypt it (in theory).  In reality, I get a

> **CryptographicException**: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

on the decryption side of the process.

Here's the `Main()` method that does all the work:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var filename = "test.encrypted";
    var plainText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";

    string password = "A better password than this";
    string salt = "Sodium Chloride";

    var padding = PaddingMode.Zeros; // I have tried every padding mode to no avail

    var encrypted = Encrypt<AesManaged>(plainText, password, salt, padding);
    File.WriteAllBytes(filename, encrypted);

    var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    var decrypted = Decrypt<AesManaged>(fileBytes, password, salt, padding);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The encrypt side:

```cs
static byte[] Encrypt<T>(string plainText, string password, string salt, PaddingMode padding)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    var saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);

    using (var algorithm = new T())
    {
        algorithm.Padding = padding;

        var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] iv = new byte[algorithm.BlockSize >> 3];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetNonZeroBytes(iv);

        var transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);


        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            writer.Write(plainText);
            writer.Flush();  
             
            // cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock() is called after writer.Flush()
            // or as part of the Dispose().
            // Calling it here causes a "you can't call that twice" exception.

            // prepend IV to the data
            return iv.Concat(buffer.ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

... and the flip side

```cs
static byte[] Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedData, string password, string salt, PaddingMode padding)
      where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    var saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);

    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);

    using (var algorithm = new T())
    {
        algorithm.Padding = padding;

        var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);

        //IV is at the beginning of the data
        var iv = encryptedData.Take(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3).ToArray();
        encryptedData = encryptedData.Skip(iv.Length).ToArray();

        var transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);

        using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
        {
            writer.Write(encryptedData);
            writer.Flush();
            return buffer.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you encode plain text and decode return byte[]? Check this, maybe useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/42834299/18452174

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imo the easiest way is to follow the MS pattern, e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=net-6.0):

- for encryption:

  ```cs
  using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
  using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
  {
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.Unicode))
      {
          writer.Write(plainText);
      }
      return iv.Concat(buffer.ToArray()).ToArray();
  }
  ```
- and for decryption:

  ```cs
  using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
  using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
  {
      return Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
  }
  ```

With this construct the call of `Close()`, `FlushFinalBlock()` etc. is triggered via the implicit `Dispose()` calls in the correct order (for details see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68202243)).

This is not the case with the old implementation, which results in incomplete encryption and decryption. In addition, the ciphertext is corrupted by the Unicode (more precisely UTF-16LE) encoding during decryption (which is the cause of the posted exception).

---

Keep in mind also the following:

- Should you later Unicode-decode the decrypted data (which is likely), it is more efficient to return a string instead of a `byte[]` in `Decrypt()` (i.e. `return reader.ReadToEnd()`).
- As for padding, PKCS7 padding should be used instead of zero padding, since PKCS#7 padding is more reliable (with respect to your comment in the code).
- Using `StreamReader#.ReadToEnd()` prevents problems related to the [breaking change in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911546/9014097).

Comment: The MS pattern is the way to go to transform I/O streams, network streams, ..etc. not for a simple context as such. Why would we need to create more objects and code If we can get the same result without doing so? Keep it simple.

Comment: @dr.null - Well, you don't have to worry about if and when which flush-calls have to be made in the approach I suggested. Also, to classify the MS example as inappropriate for this use case across the board is, I think, wrong. If keep-it-simple counts alone, you could also just use a `TransformFinalBlock`. Ultimately, the best approach depends on the specific use case and the user's preferences. My solution is meant to show an alternative, I don't claim it's the only one.

Comment: No sir, your answer is valuable to me. I just commented an IMO vs your IMO. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an encoding / stream handling mistake. You are writing ciphertext as if it was Unicode. I would recommend wrapping  the ciphertext in a `MemoryStream`, then use  an **input** `CryptoStream` i.e. one configured for reading, and then a `StreamReader` to read the text back.

Now you've fully reversed the streams, which, conceptually speaking, makes most sense. For instance, say you want to directly get the ciphertext from a file. Then you can use a `FileStream` in read mode. You can also decide to do something else with the plaintext. And, of course, if you first have an input stream, you can simply first read the IV, and then continue reading using the `CryptoStream`.

Finally, the `CryptoStream` can now clearly find out when the stream ends, and can therefore perform the final operations such as unpadding automatically, fixing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the plain text in the `Encrypt` method and `.Write` the encoding result rather than the plain text. That is, the input byte array that the [`ICryptoTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.transformfinalblock?view=netframework-4.8#system-security-cryptography-icryptotransform-transformfinalblock(system-byte()-system-int32-system-int32)) takes to process and returns the encrypted output byte array.

I'd suggest to get rid of the `StreamWriter` and write directly to the `CryptoStream`.

Here's a suggested fix.

```cs
static byte[] Encrypt<T>(string plainText, string password, string salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
    var saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);

    using (var algorithm = new T())
    {
        var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
        byte[] iv = new byte[algorithm.BlockSize >> 3];
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create().GetNonZeroBytes(iv);

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(buffer, 
            algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return iv.Concat(buffer.ToArray()).ToArray();
                    
        }
    }
}

// Return byte array if you need that and let the caller decode it.
static string Decrypt<T>(byte[] encryptedData, string password, string salt)
    where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
{
    var saltBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    var derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltBytes);

    using (var algorithm = new T())
    {
        var key = derivedBytes.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
        var iv = encryptedData.Take(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3).ToArray();

        encryptedData = encryptedData.Skip(iv.Length).ToArray();

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        using (var stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, 
            algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            stream.Write(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
            stream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
        }
    }            
}
```

... and in some caller:

```cs
var filename = "test.encrypted";
var plainText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
var password = "A better password than this";
var salt = "Sodium Chloride";
var encrypted = Encrypt<AesManaged>(plainText, password, salt);

File.WriteAllBytes(filename, encrypted);

var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
var decrypted = Decrypt<AesManaged>(fileBytes, password, salt);

Console.WriteLine(decrypted == plainText);
```

See also the generic `SymmetricCrypto<T>` class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66486747/14171304).